# Assigning to locations within a list of lists

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a table of values in Python. I generate the table this way:

```
table = [[True] * 11] * 7
```

This makes for a list of 7 lists, each of which contain 11 `True` values:

```
[[True True True True True True True True True True True],
 [True True True True True True True True True True True],
 [True True True True True True True True True True True],
 [True True True True True True True True True True True],
 [True True True True True True True True True True True],
 [True True True True True True True True True True True],
 [True True True True True True True True True True True]]
```

Say I change `table[6][4]` to `False` (`table[6][4] = False`). I would expect *only* that slot to be changed:

```
[[True True True True True  True True True True True True],
 [True True True True True  True True True True True True],
 [True True True True True  True True True True True True],
 [True True True True True  True True True True True True],
 [True True True True True  True True True True True True],
 [True True True True True  True True True True True True],
 [True True True True False True True True True True True]]
```

But apparently the 4th column in every other list is changed as well:

```
[[True True True True False True True True True True True],
 [True True True True False True True True True True True],
 [True True True True False True True True True True True],
 [True True True True False True True True True True True],
 [True True True True False True True True True True True],
 [True True True True False True True True True True True],
 [True True True True False True True True True True True]]
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do

```
table = [[True] * 11] * 7
```

you create a list with 11 `True`s and then you wrap it seven-fold in a list. Not by copying it, but by referencing it several times.

If you create 7 distinct lists, such as in

```
table = [[True] * 11 for _ in range(7)]
```

you are better off.

Answer (score 4):

Each of the 7 elements of your table points to the same list?

```
>>> x = range(5)
>>> y = x
>>> print x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print y
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x.append("ABC")
>>> print x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'ABC']
>>> print y
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'ABC']
```

You can use [`deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to make sure you are always adding a new instance of the list:

```
from copy import deepcopy
table = [[True] * 11] * 7
table = [deepcopy(x) for x in table]
# now this will behave as you expected
table[6][4] = False
```

Comment: +1 to you since you got this in first - sorry, not seeing some answers until way later :)

Comment: its not producing the expected result

Answer (score 3):

When you create a list in that manner, they are pointing to the same location in memory, so any alterations will be reflected in each list:

```
In [1]: table = [[True] * 11] * 7

In [2]: id(table[0])
Out[2]: 17815672

In [3]: id(table[1])
Out[4]: 17815672
```

As for the correct way to create the table, @glglgl's answer is the way to go.